# Does Warren Buffett hate options?

Tags: options

I just read this: https://www.quora.com/Does-Warren-Buffett-buy-options

It looks like he has a very negative opinion about (some/most) options arrangements.  Am I missing the point?  Are options really as dangerous as he things?

Comment: For a guy who hates options, you have to wonder why Buffett sells naked puts at times -  50,000 short puts  on Coca-Cola,  22,000 on  Burlington Northern as well as short puts on 4 major indices: the S&P 500, the FTSE 100 in the U.K., the Euro Stoxx 50 , and the Nikkei 225.  As for your link, there was a lot of verbal diarrhea there, particularly the Enron  diatribe.  Options can be used in very speculative ways and in very conservative ways.

Comment: @BobBaerker - They specifically talk about that in the article

Comment: And your point would be what?   FWIW, anyone who uses You Tube  vignettes from the movie "The Big Short" of actors explaining complex financial securities is really dumbing down the conversation (see your link).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My professional area is option contracts.  Yes, they are that dangerous.  On the other hand, they can be very useful and valuable parts of a very conservative portfolio.  They are somewhat like a loaded gun with no safety that has been cocked.  If you know what you are doing, they are nearly safe.  Police officers and military snipers do sometimes discharge a firearm in error or even wound themselves.  The danger in options is in how they are used.  Don't give toddlers handguns.

Berkshire Hathaway is a principal underwriter of derivative contracts, but they are also very careful.  Not all market makers are careful and certainly very many customers are careless.

If you treat them as insurance, whether you are underwriting them or buying them, then you are generally safe.  If you woke up one morning and felt that you couldn't possibly lose by buying or writing a straddle on APPL, well, please save yourself some time, money and effort and just write me a check for all of the money you were going to use.  I'll take a cruise on your money, and you will lose less.  We will both be ahead.

They are systematically dangerous in that the face amount of all outstanding derivative contracts is about 8 times planetary output.  That is roughly like buying insurance on every person for every risk on the planet eight times over.  The real risk is probably about 1/10th of that because most of those are probably offsetting contracts.  Nonetheless, it is large enough that it could bring down the OECD economies.

There isn't a good, credible method to determine the existence of an insurable interest as you would have with traditional insurances.  Furthermore, writing options are like being part of a Lloyd's association.  Broker-dealers do collect sufficient information to determine the capacities of writers.

Also, importantly, options contracts can release built up pressure on the secondary markets by offering a roughly equivalent contract.  About a decade ago, Stanard and Poors had to redefine its index rules because about 40% of WalMart is owned by the family trust.  The index treated stock as being 100% public, but the trust is under very restrictive rules and so cannot sell into the market.  Index funds were unable to buy shares at nearly any price.  Call options on WalMart or futures and forwards allowed for what amounted to the printing of non-existent shares and relieved the pressure on the prices.  So options, futures and forwards contracts can be used to improve liquidity or to cause it to vanish.

Had Standard and Poors not altered their rules, WalMart shares would likely have skyrocketed and index funds would not have been able to cover their obligations.  As a practical matter, the indices would have had to drop WalMart from indices as there wouldn't be enough tradable shares to make a market.  Had derivative contracts not existed, the price per share of WalMart would have ceased to reflect the true underlying value of WalMart and would have instead reflected the artificial demand created by indexing.

Comment: It seems that some [GOP politicians](https://www.timesofisrael.com/republicans-back-guns-for-kids-in-sacha-baron-cohens-new-show/) think that arming toddlers is a good thing!